# If $\Gamma\vdash b:\mathsf{Glue}[\phi\mapsto(T,f)]A$, then $\Gamma,\phi\vdash b:T$

Tags: type-theory, univalent-foundations

Can someone help me from where in those rules I can deduce what is printed below, i.e. that if $\Gamma\vdash b:\mathsf{Glue}[\phi\mapsto(T,f)]A$, then $\Gamma,\phi\vdash b:T$?  All the gluing types are introduced right before the paragraph (see [PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.02108.pdf)), the only preceding definition used here is $\Gamma\vdash a:A[\phi\mapsto u]$ (like in the top right rule for $\mathsf{unglue}$), but I as far as I understand, $\mathsf{Glue}[\phi\mapsto(T,f)]A$ is purely syntactical, i.e. it's just the type $\mathsf{Glue}$ with parameters $\phi, T, f, A$.

Only thing I can imagine is that is has something to do with the rule $$\Gamma\vdash\mathsf{Glue}[1_\mathbb{F}\mapsto(T,f)]A=T$$ if the $\phi$ could be baked into $\Gamma$, but as far as I understand, the face lattice is a seperate object, so one couldn't e.g. define $\Gamma':=\Gamma,\phi$.

Also, are gluing types meant to be inductive, e.g. when $b:\mathsf{Glue}[\phi\mapsto(T,f)]A$, do I know that $b$ is constructed via $\mathsf{glue}$ because this is the only constructor in $\mathsf{Glue}$?  (I assume not, just asking to be sure...)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about which rule entails it.

First, contexts $Γ$ don't just list variables, but 'face assumptions.' So $Γ,\varphi$ itself is a valid context which you could call $Γ'$ or something, and it means 'whatever $Γ$ means, and also $\varphi$ is true.'

Next, under the assumption $\varphi$, $\varphi = 1_F$. So, in the context $Γ,\varphi$, the system $[φ \mapsto (T,f)]$ is equivalent to $[1_F \mapsto (T, f)]$. And this allows the rule you mentioned to trigger.

Sometimes multiple contexts are used, one for 'normal' variable assumptions, and another for face/"cofibration" assumptions. But I think in the paper you're reading, they're just all merged into one context.

As for your second question, I believe $\mathsf{Glue}$ is arguably *coinductively* defined. You can find a discussion of that sort of thing in section 3.2 of [this paper](https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/252073/local_252073.pdf). I think it doesn't make much actual difference for non-recursive types like $\mathsf{Glue}$. But in some sense, the intuition is not that every element is necessarily 'made of' a $\mathsf{glue}$ constructor, but every element can be presented that way, because of an eta rule where you $\mathsf{glue}$ together what you get from $\mathsf{unglue}$ on any given value. But the 'projections' ($\mathsf{unglue}$ and the system) are supposed to be primary.

Comment: Can I just ask you *why* the system $[\phi\mapsto(T,f)]$ under $\Gamma$ is equivalent to $[1_\mathbb{F}\mathsf(T,f)]$ under $\Gamma,\phi$?  It makes intuitively sense, but the way I see it, $\mathsf{Glue}[\phi\mapsto(T,f)]A$ is just freshly introduced syntax and has nothing to do with the convention for $a:[\phi\mapsto u]$ introduced earlier?

Comment: An assumption $φ$ in the context could also be written $φ = 1_F$. I think it's a little confusing with the jargon about "faces," and "cofibrations." But the point is that things like $φ$ are propositions about the dimension variables, and a 'system' is a bunch of potentially overlapping cases on such propositions. The $1_F$ rule is then really saying, "if we can judge that one of the cases is actually true, then $\mathsf{Glue}$ reduces according to that case." And under the local assumption that $φ$ is true, we can judge that it is true, and the rule fires.

Comment: Various side conditions on building a 'system' ensure that if cases _do_ overlap, then it (judgmentally) doesn't matter which you pick, because they actually agree. So, syntactically, you don't have to worry about confluence problems caused by reducing according to one branch or the other when you happen to know they're true. And semantically, this is how topological 'gluing' works. The 'cofibration' propositions correspond to particular regions of a space, and you need to make sure that a definition by cases agrees on overlaps of regions to coherently glue them together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanations!  I think what confused me that for a given context, you can split it up in the pattern $\Gamma,\phi$ in various ways and get syntactically different results, which should all be judgementally equal, but I didn't find that part in the paper.  But it's so trivial that it's now easy to take it for granted.